# $A\notin B$ set thoery

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Is true or false that $A\notin B$? I think It's false.

**Proof**

Suppouse that $A\notin B$. Then for any set $A$ and $B$ is the case that $A\notin B$, this implies that $\emptyset\notin\{ \emptyset, \emptyset\}$, but this is false.

Is this proof correct?

Thank you so much.

Comment: There isn't an object which is called an "arbitrary set".

Comment: Yes, as @BrianMoehring comments, there's a problem in your formulation... It's similar to the potential (fake) problem of having $x$ be an "arbitrary" real number, so that it's not true that $x\le 0$, but it's also not true that $x>0$... seemingly.

Comment: To formalize the "arbitrary" we have to write $\forall x \forall y (x \notin y)$, that is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

While you've removed the term "arbitrary set", you have the same error.

> Suppouse [sic] that [$A,B$ are sets and] $A \not\in B$.

That's fine.

> Then for any set $A$ and $B$ is the case that $A \not\in B$,

No.  This is a faulty generalization.  Your use of the same names just confuses the issue, but there's absolutely no reason that your assumption of $A \not\in B$ should be able to, and in fact it does not, imply that "For any sets $x,y$, it is the case that $x \not\in y$."

Comment: Can you tell me, please, why it's a faulty generalization? I can't see why :(

Comment: @Ratamágica You are assuming $x \not\in y$ is true for a particular pair of sets, which you're calling $A$ and $B$.  From this assumption that it's true for **one** pair of sets, we cannot conclude it's true for **all** pairs of sets.  Such a step is called a faulty generalization.

Comment: Formally, we may introduce such a universal generalization if we have no current premise which uses those names.  That is, if there were some way of discharging your assumption that $A \not\in B$ while still concluding $A \not\in B$, then we'd be able to validly generalize, but as your counterexample of $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$ shows, we will not be able to do so [unless our theoretical underpinnings are inconsistent, but I'd like to assume ZF is consistent]

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct, hence it's not a proof.

As an example let's take the set of all real numbers as A and a set of points in a unit circle as B. Certainly $A\notin B$ because elements of B are points in a circle, not sets of numbers.

On the other hand a set $\mathbb P$ of all prime numbers is a proper subset of $\mathbb N$, the set of all natural numbers $\mathbb P\subset \mathbb N$.
As such, it is an element of a powerset of natural numbers: $\mathbb P \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Clearly, $A \notin B$ does **not** imply $\mathbb P \notin \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.